# Is it possible to embed only part of a view controller inside a container view?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to create a view controller that will reuse parts of other controllers from my app. Ideally, the new controller will have 3 containers, with one container for the header (c1) and two other containers bellow it (c2 and c3).

So for c1, I am trying to embed only the view from the controller that holds the header, but doing it in storyboard only allows me to embed the entire view controller where the header is. When I try to drag from the container into the header, the whole view controller is highlighted and I cannot select the header alone. I have also tried just copying the header, but it's A LOT of repeated code.

I will also face the same challenge when trying to embed an existing table view in c2. So is it possible to embed just part of a controller inside a container view? I don't have to stick to the storyboard, so if someone could share how they solved this programatically that would also help a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is put your reusable views in a *.xib* file. That is the way to make perfect copies of complex hierarchies of views. Every time the *.xib* file is loaded you get a fresh copy of the whole view and its subviews as you've designed it in Interface Builder. The loading must be done in code but there are ways to make a superview that does that automatically.

This screenshot demonstrates:

[image]

There is no duplication going on here, just three independent copies of the same *.xib* file, created automatically. They are all in one screen but that's just to make it easy to make the screenshot; these elements could be anywhere in the app's interface.

[image]